# Learn how to design the architecture for a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, architecture

I am a graduate student in computer science, who is also big fan of RoR. After learning RoR for nearly one year, I have finished several books and projects. Language will not be a problem, but I feel like I am stuck at the architecture and design part. For most time I have to ask myself: *is this the best way to solve this problem?* I really don't know the answer.

So I think I need to learn the way to *design* a real project: how to keep the project simple, efficient and scalable. I am planning to do it in 2 ways: first find some books related to rails design patterns, then learn some open source projects.

So my questions is, any recommandation for books/projects? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Rails for Zombies: http://railsforzombies.org/
Railscasts has really good simple video tutorials: http://railscasts.com/

If you really want to get into detail on how to structure your back-end such as your database design then you'll want to buy a dedicated book on database design. However, be aware that learning the principles of such design will take some time!